# How do I get a href link to work while using the content-type:json header to print a json later on

Tags: php, json

I have a couple of simple php pages that pull data from an API and prints the JSON it receives. I have another php index page with links to those pages. On the original pages I'm trying to include a home link to get back to the index page, but the href's that I've included don't play nice with the Content-type header I use to work with the JSON.

It also behaves differently on my raspberry pi with apache, than it does on my web hosted domain page.

```
<?php

$link = 'index.php';
echo "<a href='$link'>Home</a><br>";

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

echo "First line of data";
...
```

I expect the output to be

```
Home
First line of data
Second line
Third line
```

What I get in apache is:

```
<a href='index.php'>Home</a>
First line of data
Second line
Third line
```

What I get on hosted domain:

```
Home
First line of data Second line Third line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return JSON only, you can keep the Content-Type header.
However, if you want to have HTML elements working (such as `<a>`), you have to keep default Content-Type, and print JSON as text.

Also, as deleted post mentioned, you either have to use

```
echo('<a href="'.$link.'"></a><br>');
```

or escape double quotes

```
echo("<a href=\"".$link."\"></a><br>");
```